# Testcafe with variable server port

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm starting a web server as part of the test runner initialization. The server picks any free port, so port numbers are not constant over multiple test runs. How can I access the port number in my tests?

My testcafe config

```js
module.exports = {
    hooks: {
        testRun: {
            before: async ctx => {
                let appServerPort = await startLocalServer();
                // ???
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A test

```js
test('my test', async (t) => {
    await t.expect(true).ok();

}).page(`localhost:${ ??? }`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 ways of doing this:

1. You can create a global variable and set the server port to it. After that, you can use this variable everywhere you need.
2. Set the port to `ctx`, get it from `t.testRun.testRunCtx`, and navigate to the desired page with `t.navigateTo`. For example:

Config

```js
module.exports = {
    hooks: {
        testRun: {
            before: async ctx => {
                const appServerPort = await startLocalServer();

                ctx.port = appServerPort;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```js
test('my test', async (t) => {
    await t.navigateTo(\`localhost:${ t.testRun.testRunCtx.port }\`)
    await t.expect(true).ok();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something like testRunCtx, but couldn't find it in the docs. Is there a way to set that context when the runner is created via API instead of via config? Global variables work ok, but I would prefer to use the context object.

Comment: You can find anything about testRunCtx because it's an internal property. There is no way to set the context from your server. Actually, it will be better if you pick any free port outside your server and then put it on your server as a parameter. To start your server with the runner, you can use the [startApp](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402652/reference/testcafe-api/runner/startapp) method.